# How to run the macro on a specific opened sheet using Python

Tags: python, vba

I'm really confused here, after long hours I finally managed to call the macro via python.
The problem is it runs on wtv opened excel sheet.

I want it to run on a specific sheet.

My python code below is divided into 2 parts.

**Part 1:**

Python to open the most recently downloaded CSV file in the downloads folder

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('C:/Users/Martina/Downloads/*.csv')
latest_csv_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print(latest_csv_file)
file_name =latest_csv_file
os.startfile(file_name)
```

**Part 2:**

Calling the macro I need from my macro-enabled workbook.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
 wb = xw.books.open(r'C:\Automation\Resources\MAcro codes.xlsb')
    macroname = wb.macro('Iwebsite')
    macroname()
def python_macro(wb_path, app):
    # Optionally verify that files are all xls*, csv, or directory files

    wb = app.books.open(wb_path)
    sheet = wb.sheets.active

    # Rewrite macro in python+xlwings below
    print(sheet.range('A1').value)


with xw.App() as app:
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        path = join(os.getcwd(), arg)

        if os.path.isdir(path):
            # Optionally process further subdirectories

            files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

            for file in files:
                python_macro(file, app)

        elif os.path.isfile(path):
            python_macro(path, app)
```

Problem:

it opens my recently downloaded CSV file, and then calls the macro **but the macro runs on any open excel sheet, not the recently downloaded CSV file that has just opened**.

Answer (score 0):

To run a macro on a selected sheet in an open workbook the use of Python, you could use the subsequent steps:

First, you'll want to import the openpyxl library, which permits you to study and regulate Excel documents in Python. You can do that via way of means of jogging the subsequent command:

Next, you may want to open the Excel document and the unique sheet which you need to run the macro on. You can do that with the aid of using the usage of the burden workbook feature and the active attribute,

Comment: Hi there. Your answer looks good but could benefit from some formatting improvements. Try to use code formatting (using backticks) where appropriate. This really improves the readability.